# Realistic light/ sunlight = Sky texture + sun?

Tags: lighting, photorealism

Im trying to create the most realistic lighting to my scene. So far i have used sun light with the blackbody scale and a sky texture. I've been trying to tweak the different options to find the most realistic light during morning, noon etc.

Does any one of you have some standards for achieving the most realistic light in your scene?

If so, i would love to see your settings :-)!

Comment: Hello :). Might seem obvious, but [HDRIs](https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/) are about as realistic as it gets.

Comment: I have tried HDRIs as well, but often the environment is reflecting its colors (such as green from grass) into the windows of the houses im making. Have you tried something similar :-)?

Comment: Dynamic Sky addon included, Real Sky addon paid one ...

Comment: Ty! I'll check them out